# Disable Print Screen Key in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, key

I'm trying to disable the key Print Screen in Excel using VBA. Here is the code, he is working for other keys like RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN or even multiple keys. But it's not working for Print Screen key.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnKey "{PRTSC}", ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Because according to the documentation of the [Application.OnKey method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey) a key `{PRTSC}` does not exist. So you cannot do that.

Also note that you cannot prevent using other screenshot tools like the snipping tool or any 3ʳᵈ party tool that can make a screenshot. Even you could take out your mobile phone and take a photo of the screen. You cannot prevent any of these properly so no sense to spend time here.

Either you trust the person infront of the screen or you don't let them see the data anyway.